# How to access Sharepoint communication site's document library via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

Using Micorsoft GraphAPi i can access SharePoint team site document library, lists. But can't able to access SharePoint communication site. I there any permissions do i need to add in Api Permissions in azure portal.

Api Permissions in azure: Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Group.Read.All, Sites.Manage.All, User.Read, User.Read.All, User.ReadBasic.All

Api used for accessing SharePoint team site: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/drives

Same api used for accessing SharePoint communication site, but i got below response

Response Preview:

```
**{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": []
}**
```

Im missing any permission for accessing SharePoint communication site documents, list?

Answer (score 0):

Does your communications site have a Documents library?

I create a communications site and then queried the drives for it in the Microsoft Graph Explorer. I got a non-empty array in the response.

[image: Communications site]

[image: Graph Explorer]

Then I went into the communications site and I deleted the Documents library. The Graph Explorer is now giving me an empty array in the response.

[image: Graph Explorer]